API Token not authorized to enable/disable schedule on a job
I have setup a Rundeck job in project A that enables/disables schedule on a job in project B. I had this working for a month and now it's throwing this error:
{"error":true,"apiversion":47,"errorCode":"unauthorized","message":"(Token:G74m****) is not authorized for: /api/21/job/job-id/schedule/enable"}
Does that mean the token expired? How can I create a token that doesn't expire?
Job definition:
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: This job can be used to disable and enable the releases schedule.
  executionEnabled: true
  group: Releases
  id: 
  loglevel: INFO
  name: Disable-Enable Schedules
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - hidden: true
    name: RUNDECK_AUTH_TOKEN
    secure: true
    storagePath: keys/project/developer-tools/RUNDECK_AUTH_TOKEN
    valueExposed: true
  - enforced: true
    label: Release Schedule Action
    name: ReleaseScheduleAction
    required: true
    values:
    - Disable
    - Enable
    valuesListDelimiter: ','
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - description: Disable and/or Enable Schedules
      script: |-
        #!/bin/bash

        if [ $RD_OPTION_RELEASESCHEDULEACTION == "Disable" ]
        then
            curl --location --request POST 'https://rundeck.xxx.dev/api/21/job/job-id/schedule/disable' \
            --header 'Accept: application/json' \
            --header 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: @option.RUNDECK_AUTH_TOKEN@' \
            --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
            --data ''
        else
            curl --location --request POST 'https://rundeck.xxx.dev/api/21/job/job-id/schedule/enable' \
            --header 'Accept: application/json' \
            --header 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: @option.RUNDECK_AUTH_TOKEN@' \
            --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
            --data ''
        fi
    keepgoing: false
    pluginConfig:
      LogFilter:
      - config:
          color: yellow
          replacement: '[SECURE]'
        type: mask-passwords
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 


Thanks.

yes, that message means it might be expired, here you can set a no expiration token, or to have 1 with more than 30 days:
Rundeck DOCS
Parameter "rundeck.api.tokens.duration.max".

I did updated the rundeck.api.tokens.duration.max:0 in rundeck-config.properties file and redeployed. I am still seeing in the UI when creating a new token that expiry date is 30 days. Does this work in the community edition?
